# Checking What channel a message was sent in, discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i am making a message logger for fun and i wanted to know if with it saying what was said and who said it if i could see what channel it was in and print it, here is the logger, everything works I just wanted to add specification of channel.

code:

````
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content
  hook.send(f'|{message.author.name}|{msg}')```
````

Answer (score 2):

```py
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content
  channel = message.channel
  hook.send(f'|{message.author.name}|{msg}')
```

It is all in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#message).
If you want to also mention the channel in the a message, then just `message.channel.mention`

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this question yourself by looking at [the documentation for `on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message). The `message` parameter is a `Message` object. [The documentation for `Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message) lists the attributes which includes `channel`. If you need the channel's name, then look at [the documentation for `Channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel). Learning how to navigate and read this documentation will be incredibly helpful as you continue to work on your bot.